# Updating old app that uses DAO 3.5 and jet 3.5

Tags: ms-access, windows-7, dao, jet

So I was asked a while ago at work by my boss what it would take to update from installshield 7.0 to something else and one of the things that is holding us back is a legacy app that depends on installshield installing dao 3.5, jet 3.5, mdac and access 97 runtimes.  Updating the code to use ODBC really is not an option at all so my next thought was what about updating the db file to access 2000, and using the dao 3.6 dll and jet 4.0 but I can't seem to find any information about issues I may run into.  Is this a doable solution without having to modify code?  Other than having to redistribute the new 3.6 dll what else would I need to bundle?  Would I need to install the ofice 2000+ runtimes as the 97 runtime is currently needed?  Office will not be loaded on the machines this software runs on and they are all Windows 7 x64 with the exception of a single pc in the configuration being 32 bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on a lot of things. JET 4.0 is included with Windows 7 but it sounds like the application has an access frontend as well? You probably only need the Access 2007 or 2010 to be installed which could be included in most auto-install software.

Comment: The app has a custom front end written in C++ I have not seen it use the actual access runtimes I just know its installed by looking in the old installshield project.  My only database experience is all from .net so really not sure where to go on this.  Since JET 4.0 is included with windows 7 do I need to install the latest mdac to get dao 3.6?